# django ModelForm - initial form values

Tags: django, django-forms

I want to create an object instance where I set the (not unique) `somenotuniquenumber` myself. I want to suggest the next "free" `somenotuniquenumber` because that's the most used use case.

```
class TestForm:
    last_somenotuniquenumber = Process.objects.order_by("-somenotuniquenumber").first().somenotuniquenumber
```

If I use the form the first time the value in `last_somenotuniquenumber` is correct (let's say it's 42), but if I create a second instance, the `last_somenotuniquenumber` is still the same value (again 42, but I would expect it to be 43). Do I have to hand the `last_somenotuniquenumber` to the form and extract it in `__init__()` in order to make sure it is generated correctly on every new call of the form?

Comment: this `uid` is NOT unique and just a number. I edited my question to reflect that.

Answer (score 0):

You can't set uid at the form constructor as in web application, requests are parallel so if request1 loads the form, then uid is 42 but if the user is slow in posting the form compared to request2 then you will have 2 records with 42.

The right move is to this to the model `save` function just before the `super.save(*args,**kwargs)` to be as close as possible to the record insert operation.

Comment: This definitely happens, even if a minute pasts between two entries with only one user and one browser window (this is an admin operation anyway). I also checked the database, where the transaction was already saved minutes ago.

Comment: Yes, this is something in Metaprogramming that is heavily used in Django. The value of `last_somenotuniquenumber` is initialized once as the server starts, to prove this, you can restart the server between the requests. To solve it you can  move the definition of the field to __init__ and use self.fiellds

Comment: this is what I did now. Thanks for re-assuring.

Comment: Please approve the answer

Answer (score 0):

For completeness and other users:

```
class TestForm:
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super()__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields["some_field"].initial = SomeModel.objects.order_by("-someField").first().someField
```

This can be used to create an instance with a continuing number. Be careful that his is not aware of parallel processes that might run at the time!